# Can we use the word 'production' for compost making?

Tags: word-choice

Can we use the word **production** for compost making?

A. Methods of our study were: a) compost making, b) green house construction.

B. Methods of our study were: a) compost production, b)green house construction.

> Wastes of leave and grass, cow manures, soil, and burning husks are needed in this compost making, before it is used as a media to cultivate seeds. Could you say it as a production?

Answer (score 1):

Compost making is *not* a method of study.  It's the act of making compost. The same goes for the other three examples.  Not a single one is a method of study.

"The subject of our study was..." would be correct.

'Producing compost' is essentially synonymous (i.e. saying the same thing as ) 'making compost'.

> Grass and leaf waste, cow manure, soil and burning husks were used in the making of this compost. The resulting compost was then used as a growth medium [in which] to cultivate seeds.

or

> Grass and leaf waste, cow manure, soil and burning husks were used in the production of this compost. The resulting compost was then used as a growth medium [in which] to cultivate seeds.

or

> Grass and leaf waste, cow manure, soil and burning husks were used to make this compost. The resulting compost was then used as a growth medium [in which] to cultivate seeds.

or

> Grass and leaf waste, cow manure, soil and burning husks were used to  produce this compost. The resulting compost was then used as a growth medium [in which] to cultivate seeds.

Put together we get:

> We studied the effectiveness of various methods of making compost.  Grass and leaf waste, cow manure, soil and burning husks were used to  produce this compost. The resulting compost was then used as a growth medium [in which] to cultivate seeds.

Or perhaps you do not mean you made one type of compost out of that one mix of materials.

Perhaps you meant:

> We studied the effectiveness of making compost from various different composting materials.  We tried making batches from each of: grass and leaf waste; cow manure; a combination of soil and burning husks.  Each resulting batch of compost was then used as a growth medium [in which] to cultivate seeds.

Comment: "Compost making is _not_ a method of study." Well, I should say it depends. Wastes of leave and grass, cow manures, soil, and burning husks are needed in this **compost making**, before it is used as a media to cultivate seeds. Could you say it as a production?

Comment: No, it does not depend.  The act of making compost can be studied.  You can study the act of making compost.  You can make compost.  You **cannot** study anything by making compost.  The act of making compost produces compost.  It does not, in and of itself, produce study results.  The act of studying the making of compost produces study results.

Comment: When you  study a subject in agribusiness field, it may be applied.

Comment: No - you are missing the point.  You can study something.  You can do something.  **BUT** doing something is **NOT** a method of study.

Comment: It is the *thing* studied, **NOT** the *method* of study.